# Why is my div not showing up with jquery show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code in html like this:

```
<div id="answerTypeSection" style="visibility: hidden">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">adfadfafasdfasdfas</div>
 </div>
 <label class="control-label">adfa</label>
  adfaf
</div>

<select id="answerType" class="form-control">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>Text</option>
                            <option>A or B (Boolean)</option>
                            <option>Numeric</option>
                            <option>Photo</option>
                            <option>Files</option>
                            <option>Multi (combo)</option>
                        </select>
```

Then in javascript

```
$("#answerType").change(function () {
    var answerType = $('#answerType').val();
    console.log('in');
    var showType;

    switch(answerType) {
        case "Numeric":
            showType = "N";
            console.log('numeric');
            $("#answerTypeSection").show();
            break;
        default:
            showType = "what";
            // hide?
            console.log('hide');
            $("#answerTypeSection").hide();
            break;

    }
 // required 
});
```

console.log does end up showing 'in' and 'numeric'  , so it must be something else that i'm not doing right.   `answerTypeSection`  should show shouldn't it?

Comment: first thing - why have you not set value attribute in options?? with out value you can get its value

Comment: not needed   ,  this displays on selecting numeric      console.log('numeric');

Comment: second- css properties visibility and display are difference things

Comment: style="display: none"   ,  that was my problem I didn't use that ,   thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get the text of selected `option` element,

```
$("#answerType").change(function() {
  var answerType = $('#answerType option:selected').text(), showType;
  switch (answerType) {
    case "Numeric":
      showType = "N";
      $("#answerTypeSection").show();
      break;
    default:
      showType = "what";
      $("#answerTypeSection").hide();
      break;
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zboh47z9/)

Also, `.show()` and `.hide()` would not work with `visible:hidden`. You have to use `display:none` for making use of it. If you want to use visible property for sure then you have to change the property by using `.css()`.

---

And the best approach for this kind of situation would be setting the value attribute for the options of your select element,

```
<select id="answerType" class="form-control">
  <option value="">---</option>
  <option value="Text">Text</option>
  <option value="A or B (Boolean)">A or B (Boolean)</option>
  <option value="Numeric">Numeric</option>
  <option value="Photo">Photo</option>
  <option value="Files">Files</option>
  <option value="Multi (combo)">Multi (combo)</option>
</select>
```

And for handling the above html you have to rewrite your Js as below,

```
$("#answerType").change(function() {
  var answerType = $(this).val();
  var showType;
  switch (answerType) {
    case "Numeric":
      showType = "N";
      $("#answerTypeSection").show();
      break;
    default:
      showType = "what";
      $("#answerTypeSection").hide();
      break;
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zboh47z9/1/)

Comment: @MillRunner Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

`visibility` CSS should be manipulated via CSS like below

```
$("#answerTypeSection").css("visibility","visible")
```

Answer (score 0):

.show() changes the display style - you are using visibility:hidden to hide it which is different

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.show()` function which give display property to element and you are using `visibility:hidden` in div so your function is working fine but you are using wrong function.

Either use `.css('visibility', 'visible');` or using `style="display:none"` in div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="answerTypeSection" style="display: none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">adfadfafasdfasdfas</div>
  </div>
  <label class="control-label">adfa</label>
  adfaf
</div>

<select id="answerType" class="form-control">
  <option></option>
  <option>Text</option>
  <option>A or B (Boolean)</option>
  <option>Numeric</option>
  <option>Photo</option>
  <option>Files</option>
  <option>Multi (combo)</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("#answerType").change(function() {
  var answerType = $('#answerType').val();
  console.log('in');
  var showType;

  switch (answerType) {
    case "Numeric":
      showType = "N";
      console.log('numeric');
      $("#answerTypeSection").show();
      break;
    default:
      showType = "what";
      // hide?
      console.log('hide');
      $("#answerTypeSection").hide();
      break;

  }
  // required 
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/yped7no0/

Answer (score 0):

You div does not shows up because of the `visible` attribute in following code:

```
<div id="answerTypeSection" style="visibility: hidden">
```

The easiest way to fix this is to change the above code to this:

```
<div id="answerTypeSection" style="display: none">
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aqu83b1b/)

The reason why your code did not work is because JQuery `show()` only changes the `display` attribute and not the `visible` attribute that you were using.